# JSON returned with line break at top

Tags: php, android, json

I return JSON for my android application, I have done the same procedure in terms of returning it to the app multiple times within the project, but this call doesn't show anything from the `buffered reader` because when I call the URL directly, there is a space at the top. (See image)

[image]

This is the php code which `json_encodes` the response.

```
require '../repository/resultRepository.php';

header('content-type: application/json');

$results = resultRepository::getResultSet();

if (empty($results)){
    $results["error"] = TRUE;
    $results["error_msg"] = "Problem when bringing back results";
    echo json_encode($results);
}else{
    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

This is the code which calls the db.

```
public static function getResultSet(){
    $results = array("error" => FALSE);

    $db_results = dbClass::query("select rs.userid as id, q.question as question, an.answer as rightanswer, a.answer as useranswer, rs.correct from resultset rs
                                  inner join questions q on q.id = rs.questionid
                                  inner join answers a on a.id = rs.answerid
                                  join answers an on an.id = q.answerid");

    foreach ($db_results as $db_result) {
        $result = new result(
            $db_result->id,
            $db_result->question,
            $db_result->rightanswer,
            $db_result->useranswer,
            $db_result->correct);

        array_push($results, $result);
    }
    return $results;

}
```

Comment: Normally this happens when you have blank space before the <?php opening tag, have you tried inspecting your files already? Look for hidden characters as well.

Comment: do you use "utf-8 without bom" format fo file?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem related to your android application. If you still want to use this output on your app, you can use to `trim()` to get rid of unwanted spaces at start and end.